# nvidia enforced power limit stuck to 45W

Tags: drivers, nvidia, power-management, cuda

Nvidia enforced power limit is set and not exceeding more then 45 Watts on Ubuntu 22.04, how can I change it?

```
==============NVSMI LOG==============

Timestamp                                 : Sun Jun 25 18:55:49 2023
Driver Version                            : 530.30.02
CUDA Version                              : 12.1

Attached GPUs                             : 1
GPU 00000000:01:00.0
    Power Readings
        Power Management                  : Supported
        Power Draw                        : 29.05 W
        Power Limit                       : 125.00 W
        Default Power Limit               : 125.00 W
        Enforced Power Limit              : 45.00 W
        Min Power Limit                   : 1.00 W
        Max Power Limit                   : 140.00 W
    Power Samples
        Duration                          : 2.36 sec
        Number of Samples                 : 119
        Max                               : 31.34 W
        Min                               : 27.82 W
        Avg                               : 29.31 W
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to set it from a command line using `nvidia-smi` with the `-pl` or Power Limit switch to change the enforcement.  Since your default is showing 125 for the limit then that is what you should set it for.

*Note: You might have to enable persistence mode for it to stick first with the following command.*

```
sudo nvidia-smi -pm 1
```

The following command sets the power limit to 125W.

```
sudo nvidia-smi -pl 125
```

Comment: After running this command I receiving `Power limit for GPU 00000000:01:00.0 was set to 125.00 W from 125.00 W.
All done.` and basically nothing happening, after restarting machine GPU is still on 45 W limit

Comment: @Ms.Simpson Have you checked if the power from the power supply is connected to the NVIDIA card?  45W ~ 50W is what the PCIe slot can output.  Anything above that would require a separate power connection directly to the video card.

Comment: This is a laptop computer

Comment: @Ms.Simpson We can only guess when you don't supply information that would help like it being a laptop system.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually the power mode in BIOS resolved the issue (there are four of them). This might be specific to the laptop model, this one was Alienware m15 r7

Answer (score 0):

For anybody encountering this issue on a laptop.

Make sure your laptop is connected via it's "biggest" power brick(if it has multiple ones).

I was running some cuda tasks connected only via thunderbolt and it capped the video card power usage to 30W, as the thunderbolt was supplying only 60w.

As soon as I connected the 280 W power brick... magic, the card is now able to run at 150W.